# swift - get accurate compass heading (magneticHeading and accuracy)

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to get a single accurate value for a compass heading (which I then use with the gyro/accelerometer to calculate deviance).

Trouble is, if I stop updating the heading after the first result, I'm left with a heading value of 0.0?

I know some location services need to run for a while to give an accurate result, but how to implement this for newHeading.magneticHeading?

Any tips?  (I'm using CoreLocation with CLLocation Manager)

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
    didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        referenceHeading = newHeading.magneticHeading
        print("New reference heading = \(newHeading.magneticHeading)")
        gotReferenceHeading = true
        locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
}
```

Comment: Can't you just not call `stopUpdatingHeading`?

Comment: But when do I stopUpdatingHeading?

Comment: Up to you. Maybe based on the `headingAccuracy` and/or how often it's changing?

Comment: Just a thought, maybe heading is not available without ...whenInUseAuthorization...?

Comment: headingAccuracy returns -1.0, the device is an iPhone 4s

Comment: Read the documentation. *"A negative value means that the reported heading is invalid, which can occur when the device is uncalibrated or there is strong interference from local magnetic fields."*

Comment: I'd like to check for headingAvailability, but it's not available from locationManager.  I've tried the compass calibration from the Location Services, but the resulting headingAccuracy is still -1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an if statement based on headingAccuracy, as suggested by @jtbandes.

```
if newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0 {
    referenceHeading = newHeading.magneticHeading
    gotReferenceHeading = true
    locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
}
```

so I just keep receiving heading updates until I have a useful result.